# Java Thread Stack Allocation For One Thread Calling Another Thread Class's Function

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand what function goes on which thread stack. Let's say Class `A` extends `Thread`, and has a method `add()`. If `add()` is called from within `run()`, then I assume it would be added on top of `A`'s thread stack, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Now, what if `A` is running, but another `Thread` `B` call's `A`'s `add()` method. Would that function be added to `B`'s stack or `A`'s stack. I'm new to concurrent programming so sorry if this question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended not to extend `Thread` in most situations. Classes that extend thread don't behave any differently to those that don't.

So let's modify the question. Suppose, class `A` implements `Runnable` and additionally has a method `add`. Clearly the method `add` has absolutely nothing to do with threads. `add` is executed on the same thread as the method that called it.

Similar `run` (whether in `Thread` or `Runnable`) runs in the thread that called it. That's why you call `Thread.start` - calling `Thread.run` is pointless.